# Include Directories Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

When I attempt to `#include "postgres.h"`, I get this error `IntelliSense: cannot open source file "postgres.h"`.

I have attempted to add to the Include Directories by adding this to the end of the field: `$(pathContainingHeaderFile)`. The error remains when attempting to `#include "postgres.h"`

If I `#include "pathContainingHeaderFile\postgres.h"` there are different errors because the files referenced by `postgres.h` cannot be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just append `; pathContainingHeaderFile` to the Include Directories i.e. omit the `$(` and `)` parts. Remove giving the path in the `#include` line and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and copy-paste the header file in the same map as the executable is placed.

Comment: True, but I would need to hunt down all the other files the header references and place them with in the same directory.

Comment: True story, crappy solution but it worked for me a couple of times. I hate the MVS IntelliSense includestuff